# What is haskell's arrow associativity?

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning haskell and struggling with the following test :
Suppose we have such a type :

```
type Endo a = a -> a
```

I have to choose all types that are equivalent to  `Endo (Endo Int)`

```
(Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
(Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
Int
Int -> Int
Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
(Int -> Int) -> Int
Int -> Int -> (Int -> Int)
Int -> (Int -> Int)
Int -> Int -> Int
```

Since the type of `Endo Int` is `Int -> Int` I understand that type I need  has 4 Ints such as `(Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)`.
But I do not really understand which parenthesis are unnecessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is right associative in Haskell, so following are equivalent:

```
a -> b -> c
a -> (b -> c)
```

Function that takes arguments a and b is equivalent to function that given argument a returns function that takes argument b.

It is not left associative.

So the answer is first two.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct: `(Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)` is indeed `Endo (Endo Int)`.

Just recall that `->` associates on the right, i.e.

```
a -> b -> c     means    a -> (b -> c)
```

Given that, you should now be able to solve the exercise.